# General Backbone rule inside router, to handle all the non existent hashed url's

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my Backbone router, what can I do to handle wrong hashed routes?

For example, if someone pastes inside the browser: `http://mydomain.com/#/fffsdgs`

That route obviously does not exits - **is there a way to make a default rule in Backbone, to redirect all the non existent hashed routes to the index**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your router:

```
'*path':  'defaultRoute'
```

And handle it like this:

```
defaultRoute: function(path) {
   // Default behaviour goes here
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work: it catches routes that exist as well as non-existent ones.

Comment: If you put it at the as a last route in routes map, 'defaultRoute' will handle non-existing routes.